# boost deserialization gives me an input stream error

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, boost

So, here's a simple bit of code I'm using to deserialize an std::map

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> func(std::string filepath) {
        map<std::string, std::string> filemap;
        // read file
        ifstream ifs(filepath, ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (!ifs.good()) {
            std::cout << "failed to read file" << std::endl;
            return filemap;
        }

        string content((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

        // deserialize
        stringstream ss;
        ss << content;
        std::cout << "content length: " << content.length() << std::endl;

        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
        try {
            ia >> filemap;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        return filemap;
    }
```

Here's the thing that is making my heart palpitate. It runs fine in C++. **ALWAYS**. Again and again and again. I can deserialize the map, and do whatever I want with it. All good.

My C++ library, however, gets wrapped in CLI so that I can run it from a C# application (it has to be this way). From said C# application,

```
ia >> filemap;
```

produces an "input stream error". Not always, 19 out of 20 times I run it. I can't for the life of me understand why it behaves differently here. I'm close to pulling all my hair out.

I think the file reading part is fine. I can literally print out the contents of "content", and it looks fine.

Another funny thing that happens is, that after the first error is produced, if I wait for ~5-10 minutes, an "Debug Assertion Failed" error dialog appears, apparently from vector.h. It says "Expression: vector subscript out of range". I haven't worked out the source of that one yet, so I'm unsure if it's directly related or just a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

Binary archives are not platform independent. If you build using radically different compiler flags (c++-cli, e.g.) the layout will not be ccompatible.

If you need something more like that, use [EOS Portable Archive](https://epa.codeplex.com/).

Meanwhile:

> I can literally print out the contents of "content", and it looks fine

It's binary data. How on earth can you see it "looks fine". It "looks fine" only if you can say it's bit-for-bit identical to something known-good (and you can prove that it's good). If you know that, you have confirmation that indeed the archive portability is the problem.

Comment: PS. I forget to mention, if it's not the format itself, then you most likely have undefined behaviour elsewhere interfering (think memory or stack corruption)

Comment: That's good to know, I hadn't realized that the layout could change. I don't think that's the issue here though. If it was, I would be crashing consistently,; it's reading the same file after all. Once in a while, the program manages to run to completion and behaves as expected.

Comment: I'd still check the binary representations between the different builds. If both builds serialize to the bitwise identical file, then you know you have [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere. If they don't, then you have Undefined Behaviour because of reading the corrupt archive.

Comment: the cli build only deserializes. Still, I had the CLI program savewhatever binary data it read to my drive before crashing, and bytewise compared it directly to the original file. They're identical.

Undefined behavior seems more likely now. The thing I'm struggling with is that the program doesn't do anything else. Step one, filepath = "C:/whatever". step 2: func(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(filepath ))

Comment: Can you make the CLI build save a copy of the deserialized data by serializing it right back (to a debug file, e.g.), to see whether the outcome would be identical? If not, you have likely format incompatibilities at the source of your problem. If identical, you have to hunt for UB elsewhere (using tools like Purify, asan/ubsan, perhaps Visual Studio integrated heap checking).

Comment: So I've been experimenting a bit with this issue, and found that it seems to be related to the size of the object I'm trying to deserialize. It's a binary file about 252MB in size. If I try with a shaved-down test file around 60 mb,I get no errors. I'm still not sure, however, exactly what the issue is or how to address it.

Comment: Have you ever tried to answer the specific tests I asked about? I mean, it's all nice that you have circumstantial things that might be related, but it's still just a lead unless you actually know that the same text works in native, and doesn't in clr mode?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I should've mentioned. I tested serializing smaller objects, and compared the CLI and C++ result. They're the same. The thing is though, I couldn't serialize larger objects. If I try to, the cli application throws "bad allocation" at "oa << filemap", where oa is the boost binary_oarchive. As before, the C++ application serializes fine. I can't find any documentation that indicates there should be a size limit...

Comment: @user3765410 Now I'm really curious. Is there a way I can collaborate? A simple reproducer or perhaps a public repository? Mentioning exact compiler/library versions would also be much appreciated

Comment: Hey, sorry about taking so long to reply. I created a test application to share, and wound up having a decent amount of trouble reproducing the issue. (I'm not even totally sure that the issue I've recreated is the same one, tbh). Anyway, here's the repository: https://bitbucket.org/ajairaj/serializer_test.git, and to answer your other question; visual studio 2015 and boost 1.65.1